# C program printing unexpected output

Tags: c

I have the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void setArr(int, int);

int *arr[10]; // array of 10 int pointers

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    setArr(0, -10);
    setArr(1, 100);
    setArr(2, 200);
    setArr(3, 300);
    setArr(4, 400);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("arr[%d] -*-> %d %d\n", i, *arr[i], **(arr + i)); /* should be -10,100, 200,300,400 */
    return 0;
}

/* set arr[index], which is a pointer, to point to an integer of value v */
void setArr(int index, int v)
{
    int i = v;
    arr[index] = &i;
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
arr[0] -*-> 400 400
arr[1] -*-> 400 400
arr[2] -*-> 400 400
arr[3] -*-> 400 400
arr[4] -*-> 400 400
```

What I understand is that each element in the `arr` is a pointer and it will point to the location of the variable `i` created inside the function.

I am not sure how it could be consistently returning 400 always
What could be the reason for this output and how to correct it?

Comment: Variable i is destroyed every time you exit the function, instead of a copy of v, pass a pointer to v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition `int i = v;` inside a function automatically reserves memory for `i`. When execution of the function ends, the memory reservation is released.

Once the memory reservation is released, the C standard does not guarantee the value of any pointers to the memory, and you should not use those values.

Each time you call `setArr`, the memory is reserved and then released. A common result is that the same memory is used as it is reserved, released, reserved, released, and so on, and that the pointer appears to point to the same location. Then you have set every element of `arr` to point to the same location. However, optimization and other actions by the compiler can produce other behaviors.

Of course, that location can hold only one value at a time, so only one value is seen in it at after the calls to `setArr`.

Comment: Is it possible to make some changes inside the method `void setArr(int index, int v)
` to make it work. Because in the function call `     setArr(0, -10);
`it's a value that is being passed. The only way to set the value of an array element would be either to reserve space for the array of pointers

Comment: @joseph: Have you learned about `malloc` and `free` yet?

Comment: @joseph: One way to solve the problem would be to use values instead of pointers. You can change `int *arr[10];` to `int arr[10];` and adapt the rest of your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense.

For starters, in C, the address of a local variable like `i` will not be valid once the function containing it exits.

This means all pointers in your array are not valid outside `setArr`.

Second, C compilers usually allocate local variables on the stack, which means `i` would likely be at the same address for every call to `setArr`, so the output you are seeing is perfectly logical.

The value of `i` gets overwritten every call, and because you print it immediately after last call to `setArr` the memory, though technically free, has not been overwritten yet.

So, by luck, you get to see the result of last call to `setArr` in all your `printf` calls.